# Styling within div classes

Tags: css

I was wondering how I would style the p class="visit" on the code below because it won't allow me to just use

p.class {
color: white
}

```
<div class="OW_Container">
                    <div class="text_wrap">
                    <h1>Finding Nemo</h1>
                    <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. . </p>
                    <p class="visit"><a href="#">Visit the website here</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="Images/Slide4.png"/>
                </div><!--end OW-->
```

I presume its because it's enclosed in the div class'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use "class" in the css.

```
p.visit { color: white }
```

Also, you generally need to target A tags more specifically:

```
p.visit a { color: white }
```

Comment: Ah I'd put the wrong css down in my post, but thanks for your help, it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
p.class { color: white }
```

will color all text white in `p` tags with a class called `class` like:

```
<p class="class">white text</p>
```

Try something like:

```
p.visit { color: white }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.text_wrap p{color:#fff}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the cascading bit of CSS. Try:

```
div.class p.visit { color: white; }
```

That will style all p elements with class="visit" white but only inside of div.class.